# Externel Keyboard issue in Ubuntu14.04 on Asus-X450LA

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, asus, ibus

I'm using an external Logitec wired keyboard on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my Asus X-450LA. Suddenly I catch an issue in my external keyboard. When I press the **backspace** or **space** button, I got continuous dot (.......). 
I already removed `ibus .cache`, .config and tried `dconf-editor` to solve my issue. But this failed to solve the issue. Note that, I don't feel any issue in my laptop keyboard.
Help please?

Comment: Problem went away after a keyboard replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was not an software issue. It was hardware issue. I have changed my keyboard and everything is running fine.